# Is this functinal testing, E2E testing, or Integration testing?

Tags: testing

What can we call the testing described below?
Integration testing, functional testing, or E2E testing?

It's a set of tests that call the server's APIs to simulate the user's workflow. This test uses real server components, such as running PostgreSQL, Redis, and ElasticSearch using Docker Compose. However, this test doesn't cover the client's behavior.

I've seen this kind of test many times, and some say it's functional testing, while others say it's E2E testing.

In the sense that it simulates the user's workflow, we can call it E2E testing. However, since it doesn't cover the client's (UI) behavior, some say it's not E2E testing.

So is it functional testing? But some say functional testing focuses on one product function. In that sense, it's not functional testing as it covers multiple product functions to follow the user's workflow.
Then, is the safest way to call this just integration testing?

Answer (score 0):

These all are not mutually exclusive. I think there are several good candidates: *System Functional Tests*, *API Functional Tests* or even *System API Functional Tests*. Naming conventions in testing are far from perfect, please read [Holes in testing terminology: Test Types and Test Levels](http://qala.io/blog/holes-in-test-terminology.html).

### The goal of the tests

If you're testing the functionality with these tests - they are Functional Tests. If you're testing performance - they are Performance Tests. If your focus it the API compatibility between systems, data formats, etc - these are Integration Tests*.

### The level

You can do Unit, System testing, or something in-between (I call those Component Tests). You can come up with your own name for the level. Probably System Testing would be appropriate (because you deploy the system on a real env) or API testing (because that's what you're using). If you have other types of System tests, I'd call these System API Tests.

*Note, that Integration Testing is a very overloaded term. People call all sorts of tests Integration Tests in practice.

PS: E2E is a quite vague term. To me it doesn't seem like what you're doing is actually E2E.